# Assembly x86 REP, REPZ, REPNZ, XACQUIRE and XRELEASE instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, machine-code, intel-tsx

As I have noticed the `0xF3` binary prefix is used as:
1) repeat and decrease `ecx` until `ecx` equal to `0` in the `INS`,`OUTS`,`MOVS`,`LODS`,`STOS` instructions and called `rep`
2) repeat and decrease `ecx` until `ecx` equal to `0` or `ZF` set in the `CMPS`,`SCAS` instructions and called `repz` or `repe`

The `0xF3` binary prefix is used as:
1) repeat and decrease `ecx` until `ecx` equal to `0` or `ZF` NOT set in the `CMPS`,`SCAS` instructions and called `repnz` or `repne`

Recently noticed that `XACQUIRE`/`XRELEASE` prefixes also have the same binary values (`0xF2`,`0xF3`)

So what `XACQUIRE`/`XRELEASE` is doing (I read something about locking an memory address but they are not work line `lock` (I believe))?

Also what `0xF3 mov byte ptr [ecx],0x0` will do? (will stop at `ZF` set\not set or it will stop only at `ecx` equal to `0`)
And what `0xF2 mov byte ptr [ecx],0x0` will do?

Comment: Consult the instruction set reference. You will see things such as: _"The F3H prefix is defined for the following instructions and undefined for the rest_" and _"The XACQUIRE prefix hint can only be used with the following instructions"_. The sets do not overlap and do not include `mov`. So that's undefined. As for what `XACQUIRE`/`XRELEASE` is doing, see the section _HLE Software Interface_ in the _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 1: Basic Architecture_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting Intel Software Developer Manual 2, Section 2.1.1

> Use these prefixes
>   only with string and I/O instructions (`MOVS, CMPS, SCAS, LODS, STOS, INS`, and `OUTS`). Use of repeat prefixes
>   and/or undefined opcodes with other Intel 64 or IA-32 instructions is reserved; such use may cause unpredictable
>   behavior.
>   Some instructions may use `F2H,F3H` as a mandatory prefix to express distinct functionality.

The use of repeat prefixes with non-string non-IO instructions is undefined behaviour exactly for the reason you just discovered: Intel reuses it for expressing different flavours of the same "instruction" or to implement new extensions.

In the case of the HLE instructions (like `xacquire`), they are only valid for a specific set of instructions.
For example, `xacquire` can be used only with `ADD, ADC, AND, BTC, BTR, BTS, CMPXCHG, CMPXCHG8B, DEC, INC, NEG, NOT, OR, SBB, SUB, XOR, XADD`, and `XCHG` - these instructions don't allow repeating prefixes, so no ambiguity arises.

In general, non-relevant prefixes are ignored, so while adding a prefix to an instruction may cause undefined behaviour in future processors, it is safely ignored in older processors.

That's why support for HLE don't need to be checked explicitly:

> Hardware without HLE support will ignore the `XACQUIRE` and `XRELEASE` prefix hints and will not perform any
>   elision since these prefixes correspond to the `REPNE/REPE` IA-32 prefixes which are ignored on the instructions
>   where `XACQUIRE` and `XRELEASE` are valid.

An instruction like `0xF3 mov byte ptr [ecx],0x0` will do as `mov byte ptr [ecx],0x0`, *as today*, because the prefix is ignored.

To reiterate it explicitly: repeat prefixes are used to choose a different semantics for an instruction.

Sometimes the instruction has an explicit name and the alternative semantics are close together (e.g. `movs`, `repe movs`, `repne movs` or the fact that `tzcnt` is `0xf3 bsf`) and sometimes the instruction doesn't have an explicit name and the alternatives are less obvious (e.g. `mulsd` is `0xf2 mulps`, `mulss` is `0xf3 mulps`, `mulpd` is `0x66 mulps`).

More information on the `xacquire` instruction can be found in the Intel Software Developer Manuals or in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507787/is-intel-transactional-synchronization-extensions-new-instruction-tsx-ni-diff).